# Media player live streaming stops after 2 min

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I have a strange problem . I am trying to develop simple application which plays online radio. So for I have 7 channels. When I test them from device the streaming stops after 2 min ( it starts immediately ). But when I play them on eclipse emulator it stops after 20 min. Kindly help me. I don't want streaming to stop until user want. 
Here is the code of my first class

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.pocketjourney.media.StreamingMediaPlayer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.VideoView;

 public class HelloInterruptVideoStream extends Activity implements
    OnClickListener {
private String path = null;
// "http://192.168.9.59:8000/m3.mp3"
private VideoView video_view_;
StreamingMediaPlayer audioStreamer;

private Button room1, room2, room3, room4, room5, room6, room7;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.live_rooms);
    video_view_ = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

    room1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Room1);
    room2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Room2);
    room3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Room3);
    room4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Room4);
    room5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Room5);
    room6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Room6);
    room7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Room7);

    room1.setOnClickListener(this);
    room2.setOnClickListener(this);
    room3.setOnClickListener(this);
    room4.setOnClickListener(this);
    room5.setOnClickListener(this);
    room6.setOnClickListener(this);
    room7.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void startStreaming(String path) {
    try {

        if (audioStreamer != null) {
            audioStreamer.interrupt();
        }
        audioStreamer = new StreamingMediaPlayer(this);
        // audioStreamer.startStreaming("http://www.pocketjourney.com/downloads/pj/tutorials/audio.mp3",1717,
        // 214);
        audioStreamer.startStreaming(path, 5208);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error starting to stream audio.", e);
    }

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.Room1) {
        startStreaming("http*******************");
    }

    else if (v.getId() == R.id.Room2) {
        startStreaming("http*******************");
    }

    else if (v.getId() == R.id.Room3) {
        startStreaming("http*******************");
    }

    else if (v.getId() == R.id.Room4) {
        startStreaming("http*******************");
    }

    else if (v.getId() == R.id.Room5) {
        startStreaming("http*******************");
    }

    else if (v.getId() == R.id.Room6) {
        startStreaming("http*******************");
    }

    else if (v.getId() == R.id.Room7) {
        startStreaming("http*******************");
    }

}

}
```

My second Activity

```
 import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
 import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.net.URLConnection;

 import com.elhaso.tutinterruptvideostream.R;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.media.AudioManager;
 import android.media.MediaPlayer;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.ImageButton;
 import android.widget.MediaController;
 import android.widget.ProgressBar;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.VideoView;


public class StreamingMediaPlayer {

private static final int INTIAL_KB_BUFFER =  128*10/8;//assume 96kbps*10secs/8bits per byte


//  Track for display by progressBar

private int totalKbRead = 50;

// Create Handler to call View updates on the main UI thread.
private final Handler handler = new Handler();

private MediaPlayer     mediaPlayer;

private File downloadingMediaFile; 

private boolean isInterrupted;

private Context context;

private int counter = 0;

public StreamingMediaPlayer(Context  context) 
{
    this.context = context;

}

/**  
 * Progressivly download the media to a temporary location and update the MediaPlayer as new content becomes available.
 */  
public void startStreaming(final String mediaUrl, long  mediaLengthInKb) throws IOException {




    Runnable r = new Runnable() {   
        public void run() {   
            try {   
                Log.d("Runable", " Downloading audio here ");
                downloadAudioIncrement(mediaUrl);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Unable to initialize the MediaPlayer for fileUrl=" + mediaUrl, e);
                return;
            }   
        }   
    };   
    new Thread(r).start();
    Log.d("Thread start ","Thread startig ");
}

/**  
 * Download the url stream to a temporary location and then call the setDataSource  
 * for that local file
 */  
public void downloadAudioIncrement(String mediaUrl) throws IOException {

    URLConnection cn = new URL(mediaUrl).openConnection();   
    cn.connect();   
    InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
    if (stream == null) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Unable to create InputStream for mediaUrl:" + mediaUrl);
    }

    downloadingMediaFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"downloadingMedia.mp3");

    // Just in case a prior deletion failed because our code crashed or something, we also delete any previously 
    // downloaded file to ensure we start fresh.  If you use this code, always delete 
    // no longer used downloads else you'll quickly fill up your hard disk memory.  Of course, you can also 
    // store any previously downloaded file in a separate data cache for instant replay if you wanted as well.
    if (downloadingMediaFile.exists()) {
        downloadingMediaFile.delete();
    }

    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(downloadingMediaFile);   
    Log.d("FileOutputStream", "Creating a buffer and downloading a file");
    byte buf[] = new byte[16384];
    int totalBytesRead = 0, incrementalBytesRead = 0;
    do {
        int numread = stream.read(buf);   
        if (numread <= 0)   
            break;   
        out.write(buf, 0, numread);
        totalBytesRead += numread;
        incrementalBytesRead += numread;
        totalKbRead = totalBytesRead/1000;

        Log.d("Testing Buffer","Buffer is created now testing it ");
        testMediaBuffer();
        fireDataLoadUpdate();
    } while (validateNotInterrupted());   
        stream.close();
        Log.d("Not Interrupted","Closing Stream ");
    if (validateNotInterrupted()) {
        fireDataFullyLoaded();
    }
}  

private boolean validateNotInterrupted() {


    Log.d("Validate Not Interrupted","Media player pause ");
    if (isInterrupted) {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            //mediaPlayer.release();
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


/**
 * Test whether we need to transfer buffered data to the MediaPlayer.
 * Interacting with MediaPlayer on non-main UI thread can causes crashes to so perform this using a Handler.
 */  
private void  testMediaBuffer() {
    Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                //  Only create the MediaPlayer once we have the minimum buffered data
                if ( totalKbRead >= INTIAL_KB_BUFFER) {
                    try {
                        Log.d("Starting Media Player","Media Player starting ");
                        startMediaPlayer();
                        Log.d("Started Media Player","Media Player started");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error copying buffered conent.", e);               
                    }
                }
            } else if ( mediaPlayer.getDuration() - mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() <= 1000 ){
                Log.d("Get Duration","Getting Current Position");
                //  NOTE:  The media player has stopped at the end so transfer any existing buffered data
                //  We test for < 1second of data because the media player can stop when there is still
                //  a few milliseconds of data left to play

                transferBufferToMediaPlayer();
                Log.d("Buffer is Transfered to Media player","Buffered Media Player");
            }
        }
    };
    handler.post(updater);
}

private void startMediaPlayer() {
    try {   
        Log.d("Start Media Player","Starting Media Player ");
        File bufferedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"playingMedia" + (counter++) + ".dat");
        Log.d("Media player started"," Media Player started ");
        // We double buffer the data to avoid potential read/write errors that could happen if the 
        // download thread attempted to write at the same time the MediaPlayer was trying to read.
        // For example, we can't guarantee that the MediaPlayer won't open a file for playing and leave it locked while 
        // the media is playing.  This would permanently deadlock the file download.  To avoid such a deadloack, 
        // we move the currently loaded data to a temporary buffer file that we start playing while the remaining 
        // data downloads.  
        moveFile(downloadingMediaFile,bufferedFile);


        Log.e(getClass().getName(),"Buffered File path: " + bufferedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.e(getClass().getName(),"Buffered File length: " + bufferedFile.length()+"");


        mediaPlayer = createMediaPlayer(bufferedFile);
        // We have pre-loaded enough content and started the MediaPlayer so update the buttons & progress meters.
        mediaPlayer.start();
        startPlayProgressUpdater();         

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error initializing the MediaPlayer.", e);
        return;
    }   
}

private MediaPlayer createMediaPlayer(File mediaFile)
throws IOException {
    MediaPlayer mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(
            new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error in MediaPlayer: (" + what +") with extra (" +extra +")" );
                    return false;
                }
            });

    //  It appears that for security/permission reasons, it is better to pass a FileDescriptor rather than a direct path to the File.
    //  Also I have seen errors such as "PVMFErrNotSupported" and "Prepare failed.: status=0x1" if a file path String is passed to
    //  setDataSource().  So unless otherwise noted, we use a FileDescriptor here.
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(mediaFile);
    mPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
    Log.d("Preparing Media Player","Media Player Prepared ");
    mPlayer.prepare();
    return mPlayer;
}

/**
 * Transfer buffered data to the MediaPlayer.
 * NOTE: Interacting with a MediaPlayer on a non-main UI thread can cause thread-lock and crashes so 
 * this method should always be called using a Handler.
 */  
private void transferBufferToMediaPlayer() {
    try {
        // First determine if we need to restart the player after transferring data...e.g. perhaps the user pressed pause
        boolean wasPlaying = mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
        int curPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

        // Copy the currently downloaded content to a new buffered File.  Store the old File for deleting later. 
        File oldBufferedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"playingMedia" + counter + ".dat");
        File bufferedFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(),"playingMedia" + (counter++) + ".dat");

        //  This may be the last buffered File so ask that it be delete on exit.  If it's already deleted, then this won't mean anything.  If you want to 
        // keep and track fully downloaded files for later use, write caching code and please send me a copy.
        bufferedFile.deleteOnExit();   
        moveFile(downloadingMediaFile,bufferedFile);

        // Pause the current player now as we are about to create and start a new one.  So far (Android v1.5),
        // this always happens so quickly that the user never realized we've stopped the player and started a new one
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        // Create a new MediaPlayer rather than try to re-prepare the prior one.
        mediaPlayer = createMediaPlayer(bufferedFile);
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(curPosition);

        //  Restart if at end of prior buffered content or mediaPlayer was previously playing.  
        //  NOTE:  We test for < 1second of data because the media player can stop when there is still
        //  a few milliseconds of data left to play
        boolean atEndOfFile = mediaPlayer.getDuration() - mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() <= 1000;
        if (wasPlaying || atEndOfFile){

            Log.d("At the end of the file","Media player Starting");
            mediaPlayer.start();
            Log.d("Media Player start","Media Player started");
        }

        // Lastly delete the previously playing buffered File as it's no longer needed.
        oldBufferedFile.delete();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error updating to newly loaded content.", e);                  
    }
}

private void fireDataLoadUpdate() {
    Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {


        }
    };
    handler.post(updater);
}

private void fireDataFullyLoaded() {
    Runnable updater = new Runnable() { 
        public void run() {
            transferBufferToMediaPlayer();

            // Delete the downloaded File as it's now been transferred to the currently playing buffer file.
            downloadingMediaFile.delete();
            Log.d("Deleting Media file","Media File deleted ");

        }
    };
    handler.post(updater);
}

public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer() {
    return mediaPlayer;
}

public void startPlayProgressUpdater() {



    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        Runnable notification = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                startPlayProgressUpdater();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(notification,1000);
    }
}    

public void interrupt() {

    isInterrupted = true;
    validateNotInterrupted();
}

/**
 *  Move the file in oldLocation to newLocation.
 */
public void moveFile(File   oldLocation, File   newLocation)
throws IOException {

    if ( oldLocation.exists( )) {
        BufferedInputStream  reader = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream(oldLocation) );
        BufferedOutputStream  writer = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream(newLocation, false));
        try {
            byte[]  buff = new byte[8192];
            int numChars;
            while ( (numChars = reader.read(  buff, 0, buff.length ) ) != -1) {
                writer.write( buff, 0, numChars );
            }
        } catch( IOException ex ) {
            throw new IOException("IOException when transferring " + oldLocation.getPath() + " to " + newLocation.getPath());
        } finally {
            try {
                if ( reader != null ){                      
                    writer.close();
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch( IOException ex ){
                Log.e(getClass().getName(),"Error closing files when transferring " + oldLocation.getPath() + " to " + newLocation.getPath() ); 
            }
        }
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Old location does not exist when transferring " + oldLocation.getPath() + " to " + newLocation.getPath() );
    }
}
}
```